# How to create folder inside EAR

Tags: java, maven, ear

I have a maven project and when built it is an EAR. I need create a folder inside EAR structure so it will be "APP-INF/classes" and place a file inside. What plugin or tag in ear plugin should I use? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/). Write your own descriptor to package the `.ear` just as you want.

As a side note, The `APP-INF/classes/` folder is a proprietary feature (from Weblogic I believe). If you want to be cross-platform and compliant with the Java EE spec, You should package all the `classes/` contents in a `.jar`. See [this](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/sekhar/archive/2009/03/weblogic_to_gla.html) and Section 8.2.1 of the [Java EE 6 Spec](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/javaee-6.0-fr-oth-JSpec/)

Comment: It worked like magic after googling it a bit. Thank you, mate.

Answer (score 1):

Create the following directory tree where you have your `ear` pom:

```
.
├── pom.xml
└── src
    └── main
        └── application
            └── APP-INF
                └── classes
                    ├── MyClass.class
                    ├── OtherClass.class
                    └── SomeOtherKindOfFile.txt
```

You can read about the [earSourceDirectory](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/ear-mojo.html#earSourceDirectory) here: [Maven EAR Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/ear-mojo.html).

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. I have created a jar and altered weblogic deployment descriptor.